# loading and serving static and media files with django and aws S3

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, boto3, django-staticfiles

I am trying to configure my Django app to load static and media files to aws s3 buckets.

I have set up the following file structure:

settings.py:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = '<my_key>'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '<my_access_key>'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = '<my_bucket_name>'
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
}
AWS_LOCATION = 'static'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
STATIC_URL = 'https://%s/%s/' % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, AWS_LOCATION)
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

I have set up a user and a bucket on AWS per the instructions [here](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/08/01/how-to-setup-amazon-s3-in-a-django-project.html).

When I run `python3 manage.py collectstatic` the staticfiles compile locally in a staticfiles folder but not on AWS. I'm using Python 3.

Comment: try removing `STATIC_ROOT` from settings which tells Django where to copy your static files, in this case, *locally*

Comment: thanks - it sill copies locally even when removing that line. Any other thoughts?

Comment: I think something is wrong with the configuration of the storage back-end. I suggest follow [this tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/08/01/how-to-setup-amazon-s3-in-a-django-project.html) to configure it correctly

Comment: Maybe open a terminal and `from django.conf import settings` and make sure the settings are what you think they are, and aren't getting changed somewhere else

Comment: Thanks Dave an Lemayzeur - appreciate the assistance. Lemayzeur, I used the tutorial you linked to and encountered the same issue again - the static files appear in a newly created staticfiles folder locally when I run the collectstatic command. Any thoughts? I updated the above to reflect the new version of settings.py.